Nginx proxy routed to another nginx and capture and not capturing real IP address
I have on my local network port forwarding with a few different servers behind that single router. I have a first layer nginx proxy that I use to route to the second nginx which is the app's reverse proxy.
Here is the first layer config:
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

stream {
    upstream server1 {
        server 10.0.0.119:8443;
    }

    upstream server2 {
        server 10.0.0.126:9443; 
    }

    upstream server3 {
        server 10.0.0.119:7443; 
    }

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
        server1.co                   server1_ssl;
        server2.com                  server2_ssl;
        server3.com                  server3_ssl;
        default                      server3_ssl;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}

http {
    log_format main '$http_x_forwarded_for $remote_addr - [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_referer"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server1.co;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.0.0.119:8080; 
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server2.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.0.0.126:9080; 
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server3.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.0.0.119:7080;
            
            # Set both headers
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

here is the example app nginx config:
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

I also used a sites enabled file within the app:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server3.com;
    
    # Allow certbot authentication
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    # Redirect all other traffic to HTTPS with custom port
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host:7443$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 7443 ssl;
    server_name server3.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server3.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server3.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Add WebSocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8001/api/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

My question: with this setup how can i preserve the client request ip address in the logs? Right now it's just showing everything referred from 172.21.0.1.
I have tried adding various headers without success.
Here is an example log:
172.21.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2024:17:31:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1716 "-" "Uptime-Kuma/1.23.16" "-"
172.21.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2024:17:35:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 18_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/18.1.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-"
172.21.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2024:17:35:36 +0000] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://premiumtenant.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 18_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/18.1.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-"
172.21.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2024:17:35:36 +0000] "GET /static/js/bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://premiumtenant.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 18_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/18.1.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" "-"
172.21.0.1 - - [31/Dec/2024:17:36:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1716 "-" "Uptime-Kuma/1.23.16" "-"


You need to use ngx_http_realip_module like this in your application nginx web server, either in server or http level:
set_real_ip_from <IP address of your first nginx>;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

This will tell nginx to use IP from header instead of the incoming IP packet everywhere where it needs an IP address.
